# Fast evaluation of a variant of the convolution

Tags: algorithms, signal-processing, convolution

Suppose $\{f_n\}$ and $\{g_n\}$ are finite sequences of complex numbers with $0\leq n \leq N-1$. The convolution $\{h_n\}$ of these two sequences is
$$
h_n = \sum_{m = 0}^{N-1} f_m\; g_{n - m}\, .
$$ 
It is well-known that this convolution can be computed rapidly using a fast Fourier transform (FFT):
$$
h = {FFT}^{-1}\bigl\{FFT\{f\}\; FFT\{g\} \bigr\}\, .
$$

Suppose, however, that I have a slightly altered problem. Let $\phi(x)$ be a function of a real variable $x$, which is as smooth as we need it to be, and define the sequence $\{h_n\}$ by
$$
h_n = \sum_{m = 0}^{N-1} f_m\; \phi\left(\frac{n}{\alpha} - m\right)\, ,
$$
where $\alpha$ is a real number $>0$, and $0\leq n \leq N-1$. This is almost, but not quite, a convolution. If we had $\alpha = 1$, we could use the FFT method above to evaluate this efficiently. What about the case where $\alpha \neq 1$? Is there a way to transform this into a case that can be handled by a FFT? Or is there some other way of evaluating this quickly for large $N$? Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Thanks very much for any and all help.

Edited to note that the index $n$ in the equation above runs from $0$ to $N-1$.

Comment: Can't you just convolve with $\hat{\phi}(p) = \phi(n/\alpha)$ and scale the result accordingly? Or just use $\hat{\phi}(\alpha\omega)$ in the FFT product rather than $\hat{\phi}(\omega)$?  My point being that the above _is_ a convolution; it's just a convolution with a scaled version of $\phi$.

Comment: To help you better ask the question, I think what it is you are trying to do is combine convolution with resampling. You may want to move this post to dsp.se.

Answer (score 0):

If we let $p=n/\alpha$, then what you have written is

$$
h\left( p \right) =  \sum_{m=0}^{N-1}{f(m) \cdot \phi \left( p - m\right) },
$$

which is a normal convolution. What you want is $h(p)$ evaluated at $p=n/\alpha$, $n=0,1,2,\dots$. If we take a simple example and let $\alpha = 1/2$ so that $p=2n$, then the signal you want is $h(p)$, $p=0,2,4,6,\dots$, which implies that you can just discard every other output sample. Of course, if you are just going to discard every other output sample, why bother calculating it in the first place?

There are efficient ways to implement this combination of filtering and sample rate change for rational $\alpha$ (polyphase filters are one example that comes to mind), but it is very implementation specific and, moreover, will depend on the value of $\alpha$. Hence, I'd refer you to a signal processing text until you have a more specific question/problem.

Comment: Yes, but only part of the argument of $\phi$ in the "quasi-convolution" sum is scaled by $\alpha$.

Comment: That's what makes this possible, no? If it were $(n-m)/\alpha$, then you would not have a straight convolution anymore. Just because you are just convolving with a scaled version of $\phi(n)$ does not mean it's no longer a convolution. Let $\psi(n) = \phi(n/\alpha)$ and put it into the definition if that helps.

Comment: @JohnBarber I think maybe you are confusing resampling with convolution. The problem that you have written is, by definition, a convolution that gives you $h$ at locations $n/\alpha$, $n=0,1,\dots$. If what you want is $h(n)$ rather than $h(n/\alpha)$, that is a matter of resampling.

Comment: If it's really a convolution, then which two sequences -- explicitly -- are being convolved?  $h = f * ?$

Comment: @littleO $\phi(n/\alpha)$. Is there a mistake in my post?

Comment: Hmm well, suppose we let $g_n = \phi(n/\alpha)$.  Then $(f*g)_n = \sum_m f_m g_{n-m} = \sum_m f(m) \phi(\frac{n-m}{\alpha}) \neq \sum_m f(m) \phi(\frac{n}{\alpha} - m)$.  So, I might be confused, but it seems like $h \neq f*g$, with this choice of $g$ at least.

Comment: @littleO Using your notation, the convolution is $(f \ast g)_{n/\alpha}$, not $(f \ast g)_{n}$. I added some comments to my answer about following this with a resampling. Is my post not clear?

Comment: Maybe this is because I'm coming from a math rather than an engineering or signal processing background, but in my mind, if $f$ and $g$ are sequences, then $f*g$ should also be a sequence.  Not a function defined for all real numbers, but just a sequence.  So I'm not sure what $(f*g)_{n/\alpha}$ would mean, because the subscript isn't an integer.  But if I knew more about resampling or signal processing I might understand what you're saying.

Comment: @littleO I guess you can think of a non-integer sequence as a resampled integer sequence. Either way, I suggested that the OP move this to dsp.se, which is must better suited for this type of thing.

Comment: @littleO I tried cleaning up my answer and included a simple example where the sample rate change is by an integer factor. Hopefully, it is clearer now to those w/out experience in signal processing.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 I understand all of what you're saying, and in particular your more recent edit with the $\alpha = 1/2$ example. If $\phi$ is really a smooth, known function, then surely I can evaluate the $h_n$ for as many $n$ as I like. I'm especially interested in the case where $n$ runs over the same number of elements, and I've edited my original post to indicate that $0 \leq n \leq N-1$. For the $\alpha = 1/2$ case, I wouldn't simply throw out half of the $h_n$ values from the $\alpha=1$ case, I'd also be evaluating an additional $N/2$ new values of $h_n$. (Continued in next comment...)

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 Clearly I can evaluate the sum by brute force to get any set of $h_n$ for any (even irrational) $\alpha$, but for large $N$ this is prohibitive. Hence my original question. For $\alpha > 1$ you are correct that this is merely resampling on a finer mesh - and over a shorter interval, conserving the number of grid points at $N$. For $\alpha < 1$, however, this is more than resampling, as I'm sampling over a coarser grid than the $\alpha = 1$ case, but also a wider one. As you suggest, I may indeed take my more specific problem over to dsp. Thanks very much for your responses!